# How to call a servlet from the RESTful web services method?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets

I have written a servlet where the business logic exists. I will get a token from the calling program which calls my RESTful web service method. With this token I need to validate by using the business logic written in the serlvet. I have also mapped a Filter which sets some header values before hitting the servlet.

Now I want to hit the filter and the servlet from the RESTful web service method. am able to get the ServletContext in the below manner.

@Context 
private ServletContext servletContext;

But how to get the HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse objects. Because, I need to setAttribute the token in HttpServletRequest.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I need to set the token to Authorization Header. Below is the code.
**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.controller.HeaderFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/dummy</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**Rest Web Service Class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
@Path("/service")
public class Service {
@Path("/val/{token}")   
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")

public String setToken(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @PathParam("token") String token) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String value=token;
    if(request==null){
        System.out.println("Request null");
    }
    System.out.println("Token: " + value);
    if(request!=null){
        request.setAttribute("param", value);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/dummy").include(request, response);
    }
    return "<token>"+ "<value>"+value+" token value"+"</value>" + "</token>";
}
}
```

**Filter Class**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest=(HttpServletRequest)request;
    System.out.println("********Filter**********");
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse=(HttpServletResponse)response;
    if(request.getAttribute("param")!=null){
        String token=request.getAttribute("param").toString();

        System.out.println("Filter httpRequest: " + token);

        Wrapper requestWrapper = new Wrapper(httpRequest);
        requestWrapper.addHeader("Authorization", token);

        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);

    }
}
```

**Servlet Class**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext ctx=getServletContext();  
    System.out.println("Inside Dummy Servlet");

    System.out.println(request.getAttribute("param").toString());

    System.out.println("Request Header: "+response.getHeader("Authorization").toString());
}
```

Now am able to hit the Filter by adding the below code in web.xml for filter.

```
 <filter-mapping>
<filter-name>HeaderFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/dummy</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
```

But the valu which is set in Filter for Authorization, is null when called in servlet. I need to set the token in Authorization Header in `HeaderFilter`. Am stuck in doing this.

Comment: The same way as with `ServletContext`. Use `@Context`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using jax-rs and need to make a controler with @Context annotation :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;


@Path("helloword")
public class SampleControler {

    @GET
    public String doGetAsHtml(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse response) {
        req.setAttribute("my attr", "my object");
        .....
        return ...;
    }
}
```

That should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Am actually new to RESTful Web Services. How to use this `SampleControler ` class in my web service method. Can you show me an example?

Comment: Take a look a this page its a good starting point : mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-path-uri-matching-example In fact the JAX_RS spec define that the uri mapping path is the url to your server (hhtp:IIhost:port/contextApp) + the path given by the Path Annotation. In the exemple i give you can locally call localhost:8080/appContext/helloword

Comment: I tried this and am able to get `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`. Am hitting my servlet `SampleServlet` and before that `HeaderFilter` is written. [link]http://localhost:8080/XXXX/YYYY/service/val/VALUE_TO_BE_PASSED is the URL to hit REST Web Service. Problem is my Filter is not being hit before my servlet. Am I doing anything wrong????

Comment: really, i don't know ! I need to see your code source to give you an answers. Please Edit your question, and copy paste your source code, and indent it correctly for be aware with the site requirements.